# Factorize a numeric variable with Greek expression in labels in R

Tags: r, expression, label, r-factor

Suppose the following data frame, I want to factorized var, and label numbers to Greek letters, from 1 to alpha, 2 to beta, 3 to gamma. But the following code does not work.

```
var<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
df<-as.data.frame(var)
df$var<-factor(df$var, levels=c(1,2,3),
               labels=c("1"=expression(alpha),
                        "2"=expression(beta),
                        "3"=expression(gamma)))
```

Why the final data frame is not greek letters but just text expressions? Can anyone help me on this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your locale support these characters? Does '\u03b1' print an alpha character? If not, you'll need to change your encoding. E.g.,

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_CTYPE', 'greek')
```

Then replace your calls to `expression` with the unicode strings for alpha, beta, etc.

```
df$var<-factor(df$var, levels=c(1,2,3),
               labels=c("1"='\u03b1',
                        "2"='\u03b2',
                        "3"='\u03b3'))
```

The way you're using `expression` is only valid for plots. Unless you *really* need to have Greek letters in your factor, I suggest using the words 'alpha', 'beta', etc. until it's time to plot.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, and thx for the explanation of using "expression"~

Answer (score 0):

`df$var=factor(var,labels=c('alpha','beta','gamma'))`

This produces a dataframe with the 1,2,3 transformed into alpha, beta, gamma. Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: This gives the results what my original code did, but thx anyway.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood, glad you could get what you wanted