# How to show greek letters as the rownames of a matrix

Tags: r, knitr

I am wondering how to set the rownames of a matrix including greek letters expressions in R. I use "expression", but it seems not working. Here is my code below.

```
b.summary = matrix(0, 8, 6)
colnames(b.summary)= c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean","3rd Qu", "Max." )
rownames(b.summary)= c(expression(paste(tau, "=1", sep="")),expression(paste(sigma^2, "=1", sep="")), expression(paste(tau, "=5",sep="")), expression(paste(sigma^2, "=0.2",sep="")), expression(paste(tau, "=16", sep="")), expression(paste(sigma^2, "=0.0625",sep="")), expression(paste(tau, "1/2.25", sep="")),expression( paste(sigma^2, "=2.25", sep="")) )
```

When I type b.summary, the rownames shown is below:

```
paste(tau, "=1", sep = "")
```

instead of the latex expression.

The reason why I want the greek letters is that I am using knitr to create a dynamic document.  I want to show the result of this matrix directly instead of creating a table manually typing all the elements of the matrix using \Sexpr{} expression. The complete code chunk in knitr is

```
<<coverage.b.summary, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
 b.summary = matrix(runif(48), 8, 6)
 colnames(b.summary)= c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean","3rd Qu", "Max." )
rownames(b.summary)= labels(expression(paste(tau, "=1",     sep="")),expression(paste(sigma^2, "=1", sep="")), expression(paste(tau, "=5",sep="")), expression(paste(sigma^2, "=0.2",sep="")), expression(paste(tau, "=16", sep="")), expression(paste(sigma^2, "=0.0625",sep="")), expression(paste(tau, "=1/2.25", sep="")),expression( paste(sigma^2, "=2.25", sep="")) )
b.summary
@
```

Thank you advance for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure how you would represent something like sigma squared, but the accepted answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122912/factorize-a-numeric-variable-with-greek-expression-in-labels-in-r) might be helpful for the most part.

Comment: There are severe constraints on using a matrix object, one of which is that the rownames are character vectors. Those expressions are being coerced to  character vectors. It would be better to explain  the goals of this effort and then find a less restrictive data structure. There is no notion of LaTex representation in native R and you therefore need to think ahead about what sort of uses this data-object will be used. Furthermore the paste function in its plotmath form has no 'sep' argument.

Comment: I see! Thank you a lot for the information and advice. I will explain about the goals of this effort then!

Comment: Then I think you should  use `paste` (but not `expression`) to build rownames themselves, and you should use the tip that @nrussell provided to generate the Greek letters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the best I can do under the constraint of using a matrix. The rownames cannot be R `expression`-classed objects. I am building a named vector called 'greeks' and pulling Unicode values from it using the names, and then using argument recycling to label alternating rows with tau and sigma^2. (The inability to use expressions means cannot have sub-scripting in matrix row names.)

```
greeks=c(alpha='\u03b1', tau='\u03c4', sigma='\u03c3',
                         beta='\u03b2',
                         gamma='\u03b3')

b.summary = matrix(0, 8, 6)
colnames(b.summary)= c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean","3rd Qu", "Max." )
rownames(b.summary)= paste0(c( greeks['tau'], paste0(greeks['sigma'],"^2") ), 
                               c("=1","=1", "=5", "=0.2",
                                 "=16",  "=0.0625", "=2.25", "=2.25") )

> b.summary
           Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu Max.
τ=1           0       0      0    0      0    0
σ^2=1         0       0      0    0      0    0
τ=5           0       0      0    0      0    0
σ^2=0.2       0       0      0    0      0    0
τ=16          0       0      0    0      0    0
σ^2=0.0625    0       0      0    0      0    0
τ=2.25        0       0      0    0      0    0
σ^2=2.25      0       0      0    0      0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Tweaking @42- solution (this should be a comment, but an answer has better code formatting):

```
greeks = c(alpha='\u03b1', tau='\u03c4', sigma='\u03c3', sigmaSq='\u03c3\u00B2', beta='\u03b2', gamma='\u03b3')
b.summary = matrix(0, 8, 6)
colnames(b.summary) = c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean","3rd Qu", "Max.")
p1 = c(greeks['tau'], greeks['sigmaSq'])
p2 = c("1","1", "5", "0.2", "16",  "0.0625", "2.25", "2.25")
rownames(b.summary) = paste(p1, p2, sep="=")
b.summary
```

produces the following

```
          Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu Max.
τ=1          0       0      0    0      0    0
σ²=1         0       0      0    0      0    0
τ=5          0       0      0    0      0    0
σ²=0.2       0       0      0    0      0    0
τ=16         0       0      0    0      0    0
σ²=0.0625    0       0      0    0      0    0
τ=2.25       0       0      0    0      0    0
σ²=2.25      0       0      0    0      0    0
```

In my particular use case I am KnitR'ing a 'kable' of variance inflation factors and s.d. inflation factors for the `mtcars` dataset:

```
cars.vif = rbind(
    t(vif(cars.model)[,1]),
    t(sqrt(vif(cars.model))[,1])
)
rownames(cars.vif) = c("\u03c3", "\u03c3\u00B2")
kable(cars.vif)
```

[image: Rownames with Greek symbol and superscript]

KnitR'ing this requires `xelatex` and font that contains σ i.e. `Arial`

Comment: Another option: For the case of LaTeX output and `kable`, LaTeX syntax could be used for the rownames/colnames: `colnames(cars) <- c("$\\nu$", "$\\delta$");knitr::kable(cars, escape = FALSE)`.